# Deleting Relationship Class Programatically using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, relationship-class

I am having lots of trouble deleting the relationship that I create with this code. The last two lines below do not delete the relationship. I have tried many different things in an attempt to delete the relationship programmatically (to numerous to list) but i'm stuck pretty bad.

```vb
 Public Sub GetJoinTable2LayerCNT(ByVal pFLayer As IFeatureLayer, ByVal primaryKey As String, ByVal joinTable As ITable, ByVal foreignKey As String, ByVal relCardinality As esriRelCardinality)

  Dim dispTable As IDisplayTable = pFLayer
  Dim mrClassFactory As IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory = New MemoryRelationshipClassFactoryClass

  Dim relClass As IRelationshipClass = mrClassFactory.Open("TabletoLayer", dispTable.DisplayTable, primaryKey, joinTable, foreignKey, "Forwards", "Backwards", relCardinality)

  Dim distpRC As IDisplayRelationshipClass = pFLayer
 'display only matched rows
  distpRC.DisplayRelationshipClass(relClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftInnerJoin)

  Dim pDataset As IDataset
  pDataset = pFLayer.FeatureClass

  Dim pWK As IWorkspace
  pWK = pDataset.Workspace

  Dim pSelSet As ISelectionSet
  pSelSet = dispTable.SelectDisplayTable(Nothing, esriSelectionType.esriSelectionTypeIDSet, esriSelectionOption.esriSelectionOptionNormal, pWK)

  _featurerowcnt = pSelSet.Count
  _tablerowcnt = joinTable.RowCount(Nothing)

 'remove relationship
  Dim relClassEdit As IRelationshipClassCollectionEdit = pFLayer
  relClassEdit.RemoveAllRelationshipClasses()
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Do you get error messages if so what? Also from the code above it seems you create a relationship class but don't actually use it?